# Trying to check if mapping exists, TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool

Tags: solidity

I am checking if a struct exists in vehicleList and returning true if it exists and false if it does not.

However, the function produces an error and I can't understand why it does not work.

TypeError: Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type bool.
if (bytes(vehicleList[_registrationNo].vehicleRegistrationNo).length =! 0) {

```
function checkVehicleExists (string memory _registrationNo) public view returns (bool) {
        bool vehicleExists = false;
        if (bytes(vehicleList[_registrationNo].vehicleRegistrationNo).length =! 0) {
            vehicleExists = true;
        }
        return (vehicleExists);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` should come before the `=`, so:

```
if (bytes(vehicleList[_registrationNo].vehicleRegistrationNo).length != 0) {
  // ...
}
```

`length =! val` basically means you're assigning `length` to `!val` (not `val`). If you do that in an if-statement (`if (length = !val)`), it's the equivalent of writing this:

```
uint256 length = !val;
if (length) {
  // ...
}
```

Both the assignment and if-statement won't work here because you cannot convert from `uint256` to `bool`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Damn, that's a really silly mistake by me which I couldn't notice.

Comment: No problem! If it helped you out please mark it as answered.

Comment: TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes memory".